# Colorbox JQuery not opening on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I'm a little confused as to why this isn't working for me. I've checked the network panel in firebug and I seem to be loading all my libraries fine.

Basically, I am using a library called `Colorbox` to create a lightbox when the user clicks on an image. However currently when they click on the image nothing happens.

This is my `html`:

```
<section style="padding-left:2px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <a rel="lightbox" href="images/classes1.jpg" class="lbox_gallery_img" title="one"><img src="images/classes1.jpg" width="77" height="52" alt="" /></a>
    <a rel="lightbox" href="images/classes2.jpg" class="lbox_gallery_img" title="two"><img src="images/classes2.jpg" width="77" height="52" alt="" /></a>
    <a rel="lightbox" href="images/classes3.jpg" class="lbox_gallery_img" title="three"><img src="images/classes3.jpg" width="77" height="52" alt="" /></a>
<section>
```

this is my `JQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.lbox_gallery_img').colorbox();
});
```

Anybody know what might be going wrong?

Comment: Please link to the plugin and state the version you are using.

Comment: @Javacadabra Do you really need to include the <img> tag? Arent you referencing to the image in your <a>'s href?

Comment: shouldn't be colorbox for EACH anchor?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using either Firebug and/or Google Chrome's developer tools inspector (it is already present in chrome, press F12). 
Check the Network tab and look at the requests. This will help you figure out if there is a mistyped path, or any unreachable files. Also, you can check if there are any javascript errors when you click the 'console' button.
Also, try adding jQuery.noConflict(); in your   tag.

Comment: Suggest you to add it as a comment to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @KK I would like to do that but I can not currently because am "5" points shy of having 50, when I will be able to comment. :)